# Calling a function with setInverval to create animated shapes

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

I'm learning JavaScript and I would like to know how to create multiple animated circles in the same canvas. I've created this function so I don't have to repeat the code for all the different circles:

```
        const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

        balls = (color, x, y, dx, dy) => {

            setInterval (() => {

                canvas.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
                canvas.fillStyle = color;
                canvas.beginPath();
                canvas.arc(x, y, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                canvas.fill();

                if (x >= 600 || x <= 0) {
                    dx = -dx;
                }

                if (y >= 600 || y <= 0) {
                    dy = -dy;
                }

                x = x + dx;
                y = y + dy;

            }, 20);
        }

        balls("#00f", 35, 35, 5, 5);

        balls("#f00", 400, 35, 5, 5);
```

However it's not working correctly. Only the second ball appears in the screen, and the first ball keeps blinking.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Probably because you keep clearing the whole canvas before painting each ball. Like this you can never have both. You need to add the balls to an array and paint both in one frame.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the StackOverflow Mira! The problem with your code is calling canvas.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600). Try to animate both balls within the same interval handler. Concept is simple, draw the positions of all the objects within the same frame.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
 let myBalls=[];
//animation handler
setInterval (() => {
                canvas.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
                myBalls.forEach(ball=>{
                  canvas.fillStyle = ball.color;
                canvas.beginPath();
                canvas.arc(ball.x, ball.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                canvas.fill();

                if (ball.x >= 200 || ball.x <= 0) {
                    ball.dx = -ball.dx;
                }

                if (ball.y >= 200 || ball.y <= 0) {
                    ball.dy = -ball.dy;
                }

                ball.x = ball.x + ball.dx;
                ball.y = ball.y + ball.dy;
                });
            }, 20);
            
            
       
        balls = (color, x, y, dx, dy) => {
            myBalls.push({color, x, y, dx, dy});
        }

        balls("black", 35, 35, 5, 5);

        balls("red", 100, 35, 5, 5);
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```